# what is printjsononline in mongosh and how to replace it?

Tags: mongodb

In mongosh

```
% mongosh
Current Mongosh Log ID: 630639411fcf560da1e8d627
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.5.4
Using MongoDB:      6.0.1
Using Mongosh:      1.5.4
```

I am getting the error

```
test> printjsononline({teste : 1})
ReferenceError: printjsononline is not defined
```

But it used to work in `mongo` tool, before it was upgraded to `mongosh`. What did that function? How to replace it? This is used by an emacs mode (http://github.com/own-pt/sensetion.el) that I need to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most functions which are removed in new `mongosh` are provided by the [mongosh-snippets](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongosh-snippets/tree/main/snippets/mongocompat) package in Github.

```
load('mongonative.js');
load('mongoassert.js');
load('mongotypes.js');
```

Or write your own function:

```
if (typeof tojsononeline == 'undefined') {
   function tojsononeline(x) {
      return EJSON.stringify(x)
         .replace(/\{"\$date":"(.{19,23}Z)"\}/g, "ISODate(\"$1\")")
         .replace(/\{"\$oid":"(\w{24})"\}/g, "ObjectId(\"$1\")")
         .replace(/\{"\$numberDecimal":"(.+?)"\}/g, "Decimal128(\"$1\")");
   }
}
```

Comment: Hum, I added this code in my .mongoshrc.js, if I start mongosh without parameters, the function is defined. But if I call it with `% mongosh --quiet sensetion commands.js` then the function is not defined. The name sensation is the DB name.

Comment: any idea? see that I edited the last comment to complete it.

Comment: Oh, I got it. the `.mongorc.js` is read only AFTER the script is executed. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/mongoshrc/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the `Mongosh` [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/):

```
mongosh supports a subset of the mongo shell methods. 
Achieving feature parity between mongosh and the mongo shell is an ongoing 
effort.
```

I don't think the support for `printjsononline` is added yet. However, you can try `printjson` method of `mongosh`, if it works the same.

Check this [list](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/methods/#native-methods) to find all the methods supported by mongosh.